# display selected options in render() method in React

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, office-ui-fabric

I am learning React and I am trying to achieve the following:
I am using Dropdown list which allows a user to select multiple items. Then I am trying to add each selected option in an array. Then I am tying to display the selected items (options) in the render method, but it is not working.

Later on I would like to convert this component into a reusable one so I can perform cascading.

So, my questions are:

```
1) how can I add each selected option into an array
2) iterate through the array and display items inside the render method
3) how to make this component reusable
```

[image]

The image below shows that the length of the array is 1, but I can't display the items. It is empty.
[image]

Below I am including the code that I have so far:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { Dropdown, IDropdown, DropdownMenuItemType, IDropdownOption } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown';

import './Dropdown.Basic.Example.scss';
import { IBaseProps,BaseComponent, createRef } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

export interface IDropdownBasicExampleProps extends IBaseProps {
  loadOptions: () => Promise<IDropdownOption[]>;
  onChanged: (option: IDropdownOption, index?: number) => void;
}

export interface IDropdownBasicExampleState {
    selectedItem?: IDropdownOption;
    selectedItems: IDropdownOption[];
    loading: boolean;
    options: IDropdownOption[];
    selectedKey: string | number;
    error: string;
}
export class DropdownBasicExample extends BaseComponent<IDropdownBasicExampleProps,IDropdownBasicExampleState> {
  private _basicDropdown = createRef<IDropdown>();
  private selItem:IDropdownOption;
  constructor(props:IDropdownBasicExampleProps,state:IDropdownBasicExampleState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItem: undefined,
      selectedItems: new Array<IDropdownOption>(),
      loading: true,
      error: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      selectedKey:""
    };

  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.loadOptions();
  }


  private loadOptions(): void {
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
      error: undefined,
      options: undefined
    });

    this.props.loadOptions()
      .then((options: IDropdownOption[]): void => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          error: undefined,
          options: options
        });
      }, (error: any): void => {
        this.setState((prevState: IDropdownBasicExampleState, props: IDropdownBasicExampleProps): IDropdownBasicExampleState => {
          prevState.loading = false;
          prevState.error = error;
          return prevState;
        });
      });
  }

  public onChangeMultiSelect = (item: IDropdownOption, index): void => {
    const updatedSelectedItem = this.state.selectedItems ? this.copyArray(this.state.selectedItems) : [];
    if (item.selected) {
      // add the option if it's checked
      updatedSelectedItem.push(item.key);
    } else {
      // remove the option if it's unchecked
      const currIndex = updatedSelectedItem.indexOf(item.key);
      if (currIndex > -1) {
        updatedSelectedItem.splice(currIndex, 1);
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      selectedItems: updatedSelectedItem,
      //selectedItem:item
    });

    if (this.props.onChanged) {
       this.props.onChanged(this.state.selectedItem, index);
    }

    console.log(this.state.selectedItems);
  };

  public copyArray = (array: any[]): any[] => {
    const newArray: any[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      newArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    return newArray;
  };


  public render() {
    const { selectedItem, selectedItems } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="docs-DropdownExample">

        <Dropdown
          placeHolder="Select options"
          label="Multi-Select controlled example:"
          selectedKey={selectedItem ? selectedItem.key : undefined}
          //selectedKeys={selectedItems}
          onChanged={this.onChangeMultiSelect}

          multiSelect
          options={this.state.options}
        />

    <div>length: {this.state.selectedItems.length}</div>

            {this.state.selectedItems.map((item:IDropdownOption)=>{
              return <div>key: {item.key} {item.selected} {item.text} {item.index}</div>
            })}
       </div>
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First time define a state

```
this.state = {
    checkbox_value: []
}
```

then define checkboxs such as:

```
<input onChange = { this.checkboxValue.bind(this) } value = "0" type="checkbox" />
<input onChange = { this.checkboxValue.bind(this) } value = "2" type="checkbox" />
```

then use the function.

```
checkboxValue(event){

    let checked_list = this.state.checkbox_value;
    let check =  event.target.checked;
    let value =  event.target.value; 
    if(check){
        this.setState({
            checkbox_value: [...this.state.checkbox_value, value]
        });
    }else{
        var index = checked_list.indexOf(event.target.value);
        if (index > -1){
            checked_list.splice(index, 1);
        }
        this.setState({
            checkbox_value: checked_list
        })
    }

}
```

then you can show checked value in render using map() method for checkbox_value. I hope it is usefull for you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't use a checkbox as I am using the dropdown component from office-ui fabric. Most of the things you suggested I have included them. I will give it a try later and let you know.

Comment: Thanks but there is chenkbox inside of every dropdown element in image.I think that same logic.You can replace my each checkbox element your similar dropdown element. )